# how to display toast without finish loading context

Tags: android, notifications, toast

my game takes a long time to load from background. during loading time, the screen is black (for about 5-7 seconds, so user might think it crashes).

i decided to display a toast when entering foreground.

```
    protected void onResume() {

        System.out.println("onResume method called");
        Context context = getBaseContext();
//      Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "i appreciate your patience";

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        toast.show();


        super.onResume();
        wl.acquire();
        if (accelerometerEnabled) {
            accelerometer.enable();
        }
    }
```

but the toast shows up only after it finished resuming (which makes it useless)
i've tried getApplicationContext, getBaseContext as well as the Activity itself. 
so is it possible to add toast directly on the window without the context of my app? (maybe on the system level context)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to your game loading on the UI thread when it comes back from the background

Try moving all non-UI thread dependent logic into an AsyncTask.

This should allow your toast message to be visible while your game is loading.

Comment: can i put the toast to asynctask(and how?) instead? i don't think it is possible to put my game logic there. when entering foreground, i basically just resume the OpenGL view.

Comment: Your toast should be called from the UI thread, so it should not go into an async task.

As for restarting an OpenGL view, you should have a render state that waits for your game data to load asynchronously. In other words, when your game resumes, have a REALLY light "loading" screen appear, and kick off all your pre-processing in another thread. When your pre-processing completes, resume rendering.

The reason why you get the lag is because your surface is being recreated when you come out of the background, and you're trying to rebuild your logic on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is where a splash screen might be useful. Just place a splash screen covering all your UI in the xml, then start the loading process in an asynctask. on the asynctask's onPostExecute, set the splash layout's visibility to Gone.

Don't forget to handle orientation change.